# If T : V --> R is any linear transformation then show that there exist a vector u such that T(v) = u.v

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the space of usual 3 dimensional vectors. This is the vector space spanned by the three unit vectors {^i;^j;^k}. If T : V --> R is any linear transformation then show that there exist a vector u such that T(v) = u.v

Let v=(a1,a2,a3) and T(v)=r, r in R,  I need to show there exist u=(k1,k2,k3) such  that
k1a1+k2a2+k3a3=r

Now where to go from this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T(1,0,0)=a$ and $T(0,1,0)=b$ and $T(0,0,1)=c$. Then
$$T(x,y,z)=xT(1,0,0) + yT(0,1,0) +zT(0,0,1)=xa+yb +zc$$

Thus the vector $\mathbf{u}=(a,b,c)$